# Neuston vs pleuston

Tags: terminology, marine-biology

I was recently reading about the wonderful chondrophores, and came across the terms "neuston" and "pleuston".  According to Wikipedia, "[neuston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuston)" are "the organisms that float on the top of water ... or live right under the surface", while "[pleuston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleuston)" are "the organisms that live in the thin surface layer existing at the air-water interface of a body of water".

How are these terms used in the scientific literature?  Are pleuston considered a subset of neuston?  Some examples of organisms in one category but not the other would be helpful.

Comment: I think, these terms represent special phase where there is a confrontation of fresh water with air and marine water with air, respectively.